# Salesforce Certification - Online proctored - Software Installation

Tags: certification

I have an online proctored exam with salesforce today, but I can not find the "rules" and software installation downloads for this. I have seen this before on the webassessor website, but it seems to have gone.

Does anyone know where it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the link http://www.webassessor.com/downloads/

I found that it didn't work on Windows 8, it installs and launches and then complains that Internet Explorer isn't Internet Explorer. Maybe that was just bad luck on my part.

Comment: thats the one, /downloads... of course! Thanks!

Comment: No problem - it's surprisingly hard to find a link to it. Good luck with the exam!

Comment: Windows 8 is still not supported, but "it's coming some time in the future" according to the telephone help line.